# Entity Framework update foreign key context.set

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables `Lesson` and `Group`.

[image]

I have 4 lessons and 2 groups, all lessons are in the first group (`grp_Id=1`).

Group :

```
public partial class Group:IEntity
{
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Group()
        {
            this.Lessons = new HashSet<Lesson>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Ex_Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Factor { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
        public EntityState EntityState { get; set; }
}
```

Lesson:

```
public partial class Lesson:IEntity
{
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Lesson()
        {
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Grp_Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> FromNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ToNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CountQuestio { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Factor { get; set; }

        public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

        public EntityState EntityState { get; set; }
}
```

I use this manual to implement n-tier layer with Entity Framework [Link](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/generic-dal-using-entity-framework/)

For saving and modifying, I use this method :

```
public virtual void Update(params T[] items)
{
    using (var context = new AzmaEntities())
    {
        DbSet<T> dbSet = context.Set<T>();

        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            dbSet.Add(item);

            foreach(DbEntityEntry<IEntity> entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>())
            {
                IEntity entity = entry.Entity;
                entry.State = GetEntityState(entity.EntityState);
            }
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This is my example code to update foreign key and update lesson; when find lesson with `Id=3`, change the group and update `Grp_Id`:

```
IGroupBLL grpbll = new GroupBLL();

IList<Group> grps = new List<Group>();
grps = grpbll.GetAllGroupWithLesson();

foreach (Group grp in grps)
{
    foreach (Lesson lsn in grp.Lessons)
    {
        if(lsn.Id == 3)
        {
            lsn.EntityState = EntityState.Modified;
            lsn.Grp_Id = 2;
            break;
        }
    }
}

grpbll.UpdateGroup(grps.ToArray());
```

**Problem:**

before running `grpbll.UpdateGroup(grps.toArray())` grp_id change to 2

[image]

after run `UpdateGroup`, run `Update` method. In `Update` method after run below code change grp_Id to 1 (old grp_Id was 1)

```
DbSet<T> dbSet = context.Set<T>();

foreach (T item in items )
{
    dbSet.Add(item);

    foreach(DbEntityEntry<IEntity> entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>())
    {
        IEntity entity = entry.Entity;
        entry.State = GetEntityState(entity.EntityState);
    }
}
```

**Question**:

How to update foreign key in `lesson` ? How to change lesson is in group only change `grp_Id`?

Answer (score 0):

See below link
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-one-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx

You have to made some l changes on your code.  Try it

Comment: this is not solution. I want to use `Update` method (wrote above) to CRUD.